# In JSX, Why does a boolean return its self (checkbox scenario)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am brand new to React/JSX and don't understand why things work the way they do.

`<input type="checkbox" checked=true />` returns `<input type="checkbox checked />`
`<input type="checkbox" checked=false />` returns `<input type="checkbox" />`

If checked=true, the HTML is returned like `<input type="checkbox" checked>`. If checked=false, checked is omitted. What this looks like to me is that if a JSX property is set to true, it displays its self inline with the html. If false, it doesn't.

I can't wrap my head around how this works... because we could use the same thing for passing a value up, which would magically not be displayed in the HTML, would it?

I am having a hard time articulating myself but don't know where else to ask!

Thank you!

Comment: Because in HTML there's no `checked=false`. When it is checked, you set the `checked` attribute and when it's unchecked, you don't set any attribute. This is what React is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to do this

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={true} />
```

Same. You can leave attribute without value. It means you set it to the "true" value. Kinda short syntax for frequent case when you want to turn on some functionality of component

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

More info here
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx